# SWF works on web not intranet

Tags: asp.net, iis, flash

I have a SWF that works on the web but not over an intranet. The SWF loads it's initial XML content by binding to an asmx HTTP handler. Same code - different servers. On the intranet - a right click shows a SWF context menu - but there is no content rendered. IIS is serving up the correct MIME type (swf/flv) so I think it might be a client issue. The problem occurs on IE/Chrome/FF. Have adjusted browser intranet security settings and looked in advanced settings - no joy yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. the SWF is licenced to work on a specific www domain only.